# How to resolve APIAgeGatedError?

Tags: instagram-api

Today, I have tried to get recent user images (/users/user-id/media/recent/ with accessToken), but encountered with APIAgeGatedError. I'm confused cause i can't find documentation about this exception. I guess it related with age restriction to view contents of profile, how can i specify my age at the Instagram?

Comment: I'm also getting this problem, did you find a solution? There is so little out there about it

Comment: @user1180888, unfortunately no. Instagram support also keeps silent.

Comment: Annoying! Thanks for the response, hopefully we hear something eventually

Answer (score 0):

The APIAgeGatedError type error is generated because the content from the requested profile is restricted to a minimum age, as your guess. You can't reach the content for sure with your "general token". Perhaps with an token that has been authorized from the page you are trying to get content from. And there is no parameter to specify your age. However Instagram has no provided documentation about this.